# I have a huge ᴀʙɪ file in the ᴊꜱᴏɴ fomat but third party’s contract’s code is private. How to generate the list of function selectors?

Tags: web3js, abi

I have an [abi file with lot of functions for a large contract](https://github.com/wofgame/wofgame.github.io/raw/master/abi.txt). It would really take a lot of time to generate by hand the hash of each functions/methods.

Since the source code isn’t public, how to automatically get the full list of function selectors for such file (with the aim of getting function name for each selector hash) ?

Answer (score 1):

The ABI can be converted to a Solidity interface which contains all of the function names:

- In Python - [abi2solc](https://github.com/iamdefinitelyahuman/abi2solc)
- In Javascript - [abi2solidity](https://github.com/maxme/abi2solidity)

Comment: Doesn’t this requires having a pragma about the compiler version specified in the ᴀʙɪ (which isn’t my case) ?

Comment: The data in an ABI is generic enough that interfaces can be generated to work with ^0.5.0 or ^0.4.22 (earlier if tuple types aren't used)

Comment: Isn’t there an a browser test page for `abi2solidity`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, sorry.